How to center the out arrow of a box?
I use a code from Izaak Neutelings (https://tikz.net/categorization_events/) and adapted it for my thesis. But when I write a bigger sentence the middle arrow in "Simulações" is not centred. How can I centralize the arrow ?
% Author: Izaak Neutelings (January 2023)
\documentclass[border=1pt,tikz,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % for \text
\usepackage{physics} % for \abs
\usepackage{xspace} % for \xspace
\usepackage{bm} % for bold math \bm
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\tikzset{>=latex} 
\newcommand{\pt}    {\ensuremath{p_\text{T}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ptmiss}{\ensuremath{\pt^\text{miss}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\mvis}  {{\ensuremath{m_\text{vis}}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\GeV}   {{\ensuremath{\,\text{Ge\hspace{-.08em}V}}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\ab}[1]{\textbf{\boldmath{#1}}} % bold text & math

\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{myorange}{orange!80!yellow!90!red!90!black}
\tikzstyle{mycomment}=[inner sep=1pt,scale=0.75,align=left]
\tikzstyle{mybox}=[draw,#1!80!black,fill=#1!95!black!20,inner sep=5pt,outer sep=3pt,
thick,rounded corners=3pt,align=center,font=\bfseries]
\tikzstyle{mysmallbox}=[mybox=#1,outer sep=1.5pt]
\tikzstyle{myarrow}=[-{Latex[length=8,width=8]},#1!80!black,thick,line cap=round,line width=3]
\tikzstyle{mysmallarrow}=[-{Latex[length=6,width=6]},#1!80!black,thick,line width=1.6]


\def\connect[#1](#2)!#3!(#4){
    \draw[#1] (#2) |- ($(#2)!#3!(#4)$) node[pos=0.5] (#2-#4-1) {}
    -| (#4) node[pos=0.5] (#2-#4-2) {}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
        \def\h{-1.6} % vertical space between rows
        \def\w{2.6} % horizontal space between two main branches
        
        \node[mysmallbox=myred] (O) at (0,0) {%
            \ab{Metodologia}};      

        \node[mysmallbox=myorange] (0j) at (-\w,\h) {Revisão Bibliográfica};
        
        \node[mysmallbox=mygreen] (1j) at (3,\h) {%
            \ab{Simulações}};


        \path (0j)++(-1,\h)  node[mysmallbox=myorange] (0b)(bin1) {TTT};
        \node[mysmallbox=myorange,right=6pt of bin1] (bin3) {Simulações};
        

        \path (1j)++(-1,\h) node[mysmallbox=mygreen] (0b) {\ce{CO2} puro};
        \node[mysmallbox=mygreen,right=15pt of 0b] (1b) {%
            \ab{Dados Xxxxxxxx}};

        \connect[mysmallarrow=myred](O)!0.45!(0j);
        \connect[mysmallarrow=myred](O)!0.45!(1j);
        \connect[mysmallarrow=myorange](0j)!0.45!(bin1);
        \connect[mysmallarrow=myorange](0j)!0.45!(bin3);
        \connect[mysmallarrow=mygreen](1j)!0.45!(0b);
        \connect[mysmallarrow=mygreen](1j)!0.45!(1b);
        

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}

Then I get this output:

And I want something like that:


Try to use `forest package. With it drawing arrows as you like to have is easy.

I'd second that suggestion, but at least update the syntax and replace \tikzstyle with \tikzset. off-topic: you should really use siunitx rather than abusing units that way ;).

($(1b)!0.5!(bin3)$) gives the midpoint between (1b) and (bin3), if calc is loaded (as you're doing already. I would not use node in the definition of \connect. It just complicates things and a coordinate would be simpler and easier. there is also the tikz-ext library which makes drawing orthogonal paths (and other things) much easier.

If you use forest, most of the work is done automatically with the forked edges style from the edges library and the remainder is more efficiently and flexibly applied.
I added \strut to the contents to ensure the nodes have the same height. You really do not want to use \textbf{\boldmath{...}}. That is, in the first place, horrible and, in the second, ineffective. Moreover, it is a recipe for inconsistencies in spacing, fonts etc. You already have font=\bfseries in the style. You actually get consistent bold if you remove the wrappers.
Note that I updated your syntax and removed unnecessary code, but otherwise used your tikz definitions directly in the tree. Although I specified /tikz/... in the tree's preamble, this wasn't actually necessary and I would not normally do it. The reason I did it here was because I had started using the style in the tree directly, but then decided a forest style would be more convenient. This is fine because all forest keys are under a different prefix, but it might be confusing to code that way, so I used /tikz/ explicitly where applicable. Normally you can just write mysmallbox=blue in the tree and forest will forward it to tikz as it doesn't recognise the option1.

% original code: Izaak Neutelings (January 2023)
% forest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726781/
\documentclass[border=1pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{myorange}{orange!80!yellow!90!red!90!black}
\tikzset{%
  mybox/.style = {draw,#1!80!black,fill=#1!95!black!20,inner sep=5pt,outer sep=3pt,
  thick,rounded corners=3pt,align=center,font=\bfseries},
  mysmallbox/.style={mybox=#1,outer sep=1.5pt},
  mysmallarrow/.style={-{Latex[length=6,width=6]},#1!80!black,thick,line width=1.6},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={l sep'+=10pt},
  mysmallbox/.style={%
    for tree={%
      /tikz/mysmallbox=#1,
    },
    for descendants={%
      edge+={/tikz/mysmallarrow=#1},
    },
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    for tree={%
      content+={\strut},
    },
  },
  [Metodologia, mysmallbox=myred
    [Revisão Bibliográfica,mysmallbox=myorange
      [Simulações
      ]
      [TTT
      ]
    ]
    [Simulações, mysmallbox=mygreen
      [\ce{CO2} puro
      ]
      [Dados Xxxxxxxx
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}

1. Only if you do something stupid such as using the same name for a forest style do you need to be more careful.

Nice answer! (+1)

@Zarko thanks. I expected you to answer first ;).

oh, It was to early to me (I was just wake up and not be full functional ... )
